# Resistance between any 2 nodes on an infinite square grid

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

This question is motivated by [this xkcd comic strip](http://xkcd.com/356/)
[image].

The problem is indeed interesting, and my first recollection upon reading this was a similar problem in the book [Problems in General Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/5030008004) by I.E.Irodov(which, in my humble opinion,is a masterpiece).

The question I wanted to ask is, are there any **generalizations** of the problem known? Can be find the resistance between *any* two nodes of the grid as a function of the distance between the nodes?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [On this infinite grid of resistors, what's the equivalent resistance?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2072/)

Comment: @mark: This question is regarding the resistance between *any* two nodes.

Comment: I must note that Irodov solution (using symmetry and superposition) works only for two adjacent nodes.

Comment: @Kound It is functionally the same question.  If you read the answers to the previous question in detail, you would have known the answer to this one.  In fact, both questions were answered with a link to exactly the same web page.

Comment: There are more generalizations, how about 3D cubic grid? n-cubic grid?

Comment: @mark: Oh well, I agree.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing your title to something more informative. "Nerd sniping" is an activity which involves any problem. The problem you have asked about is not widely known under the title "the Nerd Sniping Problem."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  For example Kevin Brown did [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm) and [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath669/kmath669.htm) including this table.

[image]

so for the xkcd problem the answer is $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{\pi} \approx 0.773$.

Comment: Who is this Kevin Brown? I bought his book and I don't know anything about him.

Comment: @kmm: He is deliberately inconspicuous.  In *MathPages*, his name appears on pictures of the covers of his books and in one other place.

Comment: That's strange. I'd just want to e-mail him saying I immensely enjoyed his book.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the first solution to the general problem is given by Cserti,

> József Cserti. Application of the lattice Green’s function for calculating the resistance of an infinite network of resistors. *Am. J. Phys.* **68** no. 10, pp. 896 (2000). [doi:10.1119/1.1285881](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.1285881), [arXiv:cond-mat/9909120](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9909120) [cond-mat.mes-hall])

using lattice Green's functions (and there are references to previous partial solutions).  For your first question, the recurrence relation that gives the resistance between nodes in a square lattice is equation 32.  The paper also describes how to solve or derive asymptotics for rectangular lattices, triangular lattices, honeycombs, and cubic lattices in higher dimensions.