# Variation of infinite grid of ideal one-ohm resistors: what would be the equivalent resistance between 2 points in a 3D lattice?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'm sure that many here are familiar with this famous problem that popped up on xkcd one day:

> **On this infinite grid of ideal one-ohm resistors, what's the equivalent resistance between the two marked nodes?**
>
> [image: Nerd Sniping]

I am intensely curious, however: *what if instead of an infinite grid of ideal one-ohm resistors, we had an infinite lattice?* (interestingly, I could not find a single image on google illustrating this) This brings up two interesting questions:

- What is the equivalent resistance between two nodes that lie on the same plane of the lattice?
- What is the equivalent resistance between two nodes that do **not** lie on the same plane of the lattice?

I've searched the site a fair bit, and this question does not seem to have been asked. I don't know anywhere near enough about electrical engineering and circuit physics to even begin tackling this problem, but I would love to see something akin to a solution.

Comment: There's a way to write down the resistance between two points on the 2D grid as an integral. My *guess* is that when you go to 3D the form of that integral is preserved. If this question is still unanswered tomorrow night I'll try to reconstruct those integrals for you.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10308/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good reference was given in [an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47116) to a related question: [Cserti 2000](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.1285881) ([arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9909120), whose numbers I'll be referring to) solved a number of generalizations of the 2D lattice problem.

For a $d$-dimensional lattice, the resistance between the origin and the point $(l_1, \ldots, l_d)$ is given by eq. 18 in that paper:
$$ R(l_1, \ldots, l_d) = R_0 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{2\pi} \cdots \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}x_d}{2\pi} \left(1 - \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(l_1x_1+\cdots+l_dx_d)}\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^d (1 - \cos x_i)\right)^{-1}, $$
where $R_0$ is the resistance of a single resistor.

The author goes on to talk about the specific case of $d = 3$, where in eq. 35 it is shown that
$$ R(l_1, l_2, l_3) = R_0 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{d}x_3}{2\pi} \frac{1-\cos(l_1x_1+l_2x_2+l_3x_3)}{3-\cos x_1-\cos x_2-\cos x_3}. $$
Moreover, as one might expect with enough dimensions, the increase in the number of paths between points can grow fast enough to balance the increase in path length. Indeed, for $d = 3$ the resistance between two points asymptotes to a constant as the points diverge. The paper gives the constant in several forms, one of which is eq. 39:
$$ R_\infty = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{96\pi^3} \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{24}\right) \Gamma^2\left(\frac{11}{24}\right) R_0 \approx 0.505 R_0. $$
Note that this means even if we stick to a single plane in a 3D lattice, the existence of the third dimension drastically alters the qualitative behavior as we move the two nodes apart, since in 2D $R_\infty$ diverges.

Comment: Just to make sure that I am reading this correctly: is the resistance above valid for *any* two points throughout the lattice? Or only with the distance between them that I posit in the question?

Comment: Yes, the formulas hold for any points (one taken to be the origin). The knight's move case is $(l_1,l_2,l_3) = (0,1,2)$ in any order.

Comment: Quite interesting. Thank you very much for your answer. :)