# The resistor puzzle: with or without higher mathematics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, fourier-transform, mathematics

A fairly well-known puzzle asks for the resistance between two adjacent nodes of
an infinite square resistor grid, like the points A and B in the drawing.
If the resistors are all $1\Omega$, the answer is $\frac12\Omega$, which can be
seen by superposition of the two situations where you inject a current in node A,
or an opposite current in node B, and use symmetry to argue that
in each situation $1/4$th of the current flows through each of the directly
adjacent resistors.

**Question:** Is there also a *simple way to see* the impedance between diagonally adjacent
nodes A and D? (And maybe even for other cases, like A to C, or the knight-jump A to E, etc.?)

[image: grid]

Those resistance values *can be calculated* with higher mathematics but that
method is not convincing to many people (for instance some will insist that points
A and D should give a resistance of $\frac12\sqrt2$). For
completeness, nevertheless, here we'll derive the values in that way.
We denote nodes on the grid by vectors ${\bf x}=(n,m)$ with integer coordinates.
From Kirchhoff's and Ohm's laws we then have for the voltage $V({\bf x})$ on each node:
$$ I({\bf x}) = 4V({\bf x})-V({\bf x}-{\bf e}_1)-V({\bf x}+{\bf e}_1)
                -V({\bf x}-{\bf e}_2)-V({\bf x}+{\bf e}_2) \tag{Eq1}
 $$
with ${\bf e}_1$ and ${\bf e}_2$ the basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and $I({\bf x})$ an external current injected in node ${\bf x}$. Since this is essentially the discrete Laplace operator, we can transform to the Fourier domain and write:

$$
 V({\bf x}) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dk}{2\pi} \
           \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq}{2\pi} \ e^{i{\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}}\ \hat V({\bf p})
  $$
where the transformed $\hat V$ in Fourier space now depends on ${\bf p}=(k,q)$. Doing the same for $I({\bf x})$ we can invert the discrete Laplace, and write  [Eq1] as:
$$
 \hat V({\bf p}) = \frac1{4-2\cos k-2\cos q} \ \hat  I({\bf p}) 
$$ $$
\Rightarrow \quad
 V({\bf x}) =  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dk}{2\pi} \
           \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq}{2\pi} \ \frac{e^{i{\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}}}{4-2\cos k-2\cos q} \ \hat  I({\bf p})  \tag{Eq2}
  $$
If we now inject two opposite unit currents at points A and B, a trivial Fourier transform from ${\bf x}$ space to ${\bf p}$ space will give us:
$$
 \hat I({\bf p}) = e^{-i {\bf p}\cdot{\bf x_B}} - e^{-i {\bf p}\cdot{\bf x_A}}
$$
Using [Eq2] we then transform back and find the potential difference between any two other points C and D, as:
$$
V({\bf x}_D)-V({\bf x}_C) =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \frac{dk}{2\pi} \ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq}{2\pi}
 \ \frac{e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}_D} -e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}_C}  }
{4-2\cos k-2\cos q} \ (e^{-i {\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}_B} - e^{-i {\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}_A}).
  $$

For the resistor puzzle, points C and D are the same as A and B, and we can choose one of them to be the origin, which leaves us with one vector ${\bf x} = {\bf x}_B $. The numerator in the integral then becomes:

$$
(1-e^{-i {\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}}) \ (1-e^{i {\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}}) = 
2-2\cos({\bf p}\cdot{\bf x}) =
2-2\cos(n k + m q) =
$$ $$
= 2-2\cos(n k)\cos(m q)+2\sin(n k)\sin(m q).  
$$
Since the denominator is totally symmetric in $q$ and $k$ we can keep only the symmetric part of this last expression. Also we'll subsequently use four times the integral in only one quadrant. If we then denote $\vec B-\vec A={\bf x}=(n,m)$ we get:

$$ R(n,m)=
8 \int_0^\pi  \frac{dk}{2\pi} \ \int_0^\pi \frac{dq}{2\pi}
 \ \ \frac{1-\cos(n k)\cos(m q) }
{4-2\cos k-2\cos q}.
  $$

For the  case $m=0$, doing the $q$ integral leaves us with:

$$ R(n,0)=
 \int_0^\pi  \frac{dk}{\pi}  
 \ \frac{1 - \cos(k n)} 
{\sqrt{3-4\cos k +\cos^2 k}}.
  $$

Doing also the $k$ integral then shows us $R(1,0)=1/2$, which we already knew, just like $R(0,0)=0$, but we also see that for instance $R(2,0)= 2-4/\pi$, which is new!
We can of course redo the $q$ integral for  $m=1$. This gives:

$$ R(n,1)=
 \int_0^\pi  \frac{dk}{\pi} \Big(\cos(k n) + 
   \frac{(\cos k - 2) \cos(k n) + 1} 
{\sqrt{3-4\cos k +\cos^2 k}}
 \Big).
  $$
and this finally gives us the "diagonal" resistance: $R(1,1)=2/\pi$, which is clearly 10% smaller than the $\frac12\sqrt2\ $ some might have expected, and the knight jump: $R(2,1)=4/\pi-1/2$. In summary:

$$
  R(0,1) = \frac12
$$ $$
\qquad R(0,2) = 2-\frac4\pi
$$ $$
\quad\qquad  R(0,3) = \frac{17}2-\frac{24}\pi
$$ $$
 R(1,1) = \frac2\pi
$$ $$
\qquad  R(1,2) = \frac4\pi-\frac12
$$ $$
\qquad R(1,3) = \frac{46}{3\pi}-4
$$

Of course the procedure can nicely be generalized, e.g. for the anisotropic case where the horizontal resistors have a different value than the vertical ones, or for more than $2$ dimensions. And the approach is of course standard practice for particle physicists, but it is  still an interesting question whether at least some of these values, like the diagonal $R(1,1)$, have a simpler derivation...

Comment: https://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2072/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10308/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The $\pi$ (a transcendental number) in the expression suggests there should be integrals or summations of infinitely long series involved. So, depending on how "simple" you are looking for, the answer is probably no. The simplest you could hope for still gets an infinite series like $(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...)$ somewhere along the proof.

Comment: Sorry for missing the duplicates! Stackexchange did not show them when I submitted this. I should have done a more active search, of course... (Anyhow they do not give an answer to finding a *simpler* derivation, in fact the derivations I see look more like unnecessary long.)